# Installation failed SteerMouse

Tags: installation, osx-yosemite, logitech-mouse

To be able to fully use my Logitech AnyWhere Mouse, I looked to install third party softwares

I'm currently running `Yosemite 10.10.2` and unable to install `SteerMouse 4.2.2`.

After many rebooting or fixed permissions under `DiskUtility` app, I get the same result.

Here's an example of the `Console` log message after a try:

```
10/04/15 13:54:40,765 Installer[867]:
  The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail.
  Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

It's exactly the same problem with `USB-Overdrive-31`.

What I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Pure guesswork, but it may be the kexts it's trying to install. First thing I'd test is if it works with Yosemite's kext-signing switched off - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163059/how-can-i-disable-kext-signing-in-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite

Comment: Nice try but nope. I already deactivated it.

Comment: Then I guess it might be time to contact plenty.jp - though if USB Overdrive is failing the same way, I think the solution is closer to home, but I've no idea how to troubleshoot at that level, sorry. First thing might be to test from a virgin admin account & see how it goes

Comment: On the way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I saw that some directory was missing, something in `/private/tmp...`
which prevented an object creation, leading to a null variable.

I went to the `/private/tmp` directory a saw file named `.keystone_install_lock`
 which I suppressed and relaunch an installation. It was just fine after.